# Unable to Add Customer in QuickBook Desktop with Extra Fields

Tags: asp.net, web-services, desktop, quickbooks

I am getting error in web connector log when I try to send extra fields

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerAddRq requestID="1">
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>Mohammed Ibrahim</Name>
                <CompanyName>IBM</CompanyName>
                <FirstName>Mohammed</FirstName>
                <LastName>Ibrahim</LastName>
                <MiddleName>as</MiddleName>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>hyderabad</Addr1>
                    <City>Hyderabad</City>
                    <State>Telangana</State>
                    <PostalCode>56564</PostalCode>
                    <Country>India</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <Phone>78998797879</Phone>
                <Fax>+45545555</Fax>
                <Email>ibbu@mtitdc.net</Email>
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for the error message:

> 0x80040400 QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

You'll find that **order matters when building qbXML requests**.

For example, if the qbXML request is defined in the OSR like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name>STRTYPE</Name>
        <FirstName>STRTYPE</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>STRTYPE</MiddleName>
        <LastName>STRTYPE</LastName>
        ...
```

Then the below will not work (because the `<Name>…</Name>` and `<FirstName>…</FirstName>` tags are in the opposite order):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>        
        <Name>Keith R Palmer</Name>
        <MiddleName>R</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
        ...
```

Please go refer to the QuickBooks OSR reference:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

And make sure you're sending your qbXML tags in the correct order.